# Remove all matching elements from vector of non-primitive objects in C++

Tags: c++, vector, erase

Let's say I have a class:

```
class sampleVector
{
  public:
  int a;
  int b;
  string c;
}
```

Now I have a vector with multiple objects of sampleVector but the vector has 2(**multiple**) **consecutive** objects of sampleVector which have same values of a(say 5) and b(say 10).

Now I want to delete all the sampleVector objects from the vector that have a=5 and b=10.

The issue is, for multiple consecutive occurrences, below is one way to do:

```
for (;it!=itEnd;it++)
{
    if (it->getA() == 5 && it->getB() == 10)
    {
        vec.erase(it);
        it=vec.begin(); // Resetting this is must
    }
}
```

But I want to know how to use "remove" for this as the below doesn't work:

```
for (;it!=itEnd;it++)
        {
                if (it->getA() == 5 && it->getB() == 10)
                {
                        vec2.erase(remove(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), *it), vec2.end()); // doesn't even compile
                }
        }
```

We can use this way of removing when we have a vector of primitive datatypes and we have a specific value that we need to delete. But in case of vector of non-primitive datatype, how can we use "remove" by passing iterator instead of value?

Comment: Declare an `operator ==` for the class and use `std::remove` or use `std::remove_if` with a function that can compare them.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I suggest you turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to use a loop for this as `std::remove` [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) states;

> Removes all elements satisfying specific criteria from the range [first, last)

As you want to remove specific items that only match part of your class you should use `std::remove_if` and supply a predicate:

> template< class ForwardIt, class UnaryPredicate >
>   ForwardIt remove_if( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, UnaryPredicate p );

For example:

```
std::remove_if(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec),
            [](sampleVector& v) { return (v.a == 5 && v.b==10); });
```

You can then pass this into `std::erase` as you were previously.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that in two ways: add a compare operator to your class or use `std::remove_if` with a function that does the comparing.

### Add compare operator

This approach is preferred in most cases, if you have access to the class `sampleVector`. This way, you distribute the operator together with your class, so other users won't have to write functions for that. Since the elements are public, you could also have the operator as non-member function, but non-member function won't have access to private fields.

```
class sampleVector
{
  public:
  int a;
  int b;
  string c;
  bool operator==(const sampleVector& other);
}

bool sampleVector::operator==(const sampleVector& other)
{
  return a == other.a && b == other.b;
}

//somewhere else
sampleVector elementToRemove {5, 10, ""}; //or however you find the element you want to remove
std::erase(std::remove(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), elementToRemove), vec2.end());
```

### Use `std::remove_if`

This approach is better, if you can't modify the content of `sampleVector` or if there are multiple possibilities for comparing the classes (e.g. here you only check `a` and `b`, but in other situations you want to compare `c` as well). It won't work if you want to compare private members (unless you provide getters for them).

```
std::erase(std::remove_if(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), [](const sampleVector& v) {
                                                    return v.a == 5 && v.b == 10;}), vec2.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually std::remove algorithm don't remove vector elements, but shifts those at the end.
In your case, you can use next approach:

```
auto it = std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](auto&& item)
{ return (item.a == 5 && item.b == 10); });
vec.erase(it, vec.end());
```

Remarks:
1-st and 2-nd arguments of std::remove_if - is iterators that indicates on begin and end of vector respectively.
3-rd argument - is callable object (in our case is lambda), that return true - if currently object need to delete and false else.
Return value of this algorithm - is iterator on first removing object.

Answer (score 1):

The example with [std::remove_if](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) and [vector.erase](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct SampleVector
{
  int a;
  int b;
  std::string c;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& to, const SampleVector & v)
{
    return to << "{ a=" << v.a << ", b=" << v.b << ", c=" << v.c << " }";
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

   std::vector< SampleVector > data = { {5,10,"5-10"}, {3,12,"3-12"}, {5,10,"5-10"} };

   std::cout << "Before [";
   std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), [] (const SampleVector& v) {
            std::cout << ' ' << v << ' ';
    } );
   std::cout << ']' << std::endl;

   data.erase( std::remove_if(data.begin(), data.end(), [] (const SampleVector& v)
    { return 5 == v.a && 10 == v.b; } ), data.end() );


   std::cout << "After [";
   std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), [] (const SampleVector& v) {
            std::cout << ' ' << v << ' ';
    } );
   std::cout << ']' << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```